# I have an issue with SQL IN query I'm storing multiple employees id in a table separated with comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with SQL `IN` query: I'm storing multiple employee IDs in a table, separated with commas for each `task`.  When I try to fetch a `task` with an `IN` query, I'm not getting the row which contains the employee IDs.

My query is:

```
select 
   t.*, 
   e.emp_name, 
   d.department_name 
from 
   task as t 
   LEFT JOIN employee as e on(e.emp_id=t.assign_to) 
   LEFT JOIN department as d on(d.depart_id=e.depart_id) 
where 
   t.task_status='PENDING' 
   AND t.created_by!='31' 
   AND t.assign_to IN ('31') 
order by 
   t.task_id DESC
```

The stored value in database [image]

Answer (score 1):

IN doesn't work like that

Example if your data looks like:

```
ManagerName, ManagerOf
'John', 'Steve,Sarah,Dave'
```

You can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM managers WHERE 'sarah' IN ManagerOf
```

IN is best conceived as an extension of OR:

```
SELECT * FROM managers WHERE managerof IN ('Sarah','Steve')
--is the same as:
SELECT * FROM managers WHERE 
  managerof = 'Sarah' OR
  managerof = 'Steve'
```

There would be as many OR clauses as there are items in the IN list.

Hopefully this shows you why the database doesn't return you any results.. Because a value of `Steve,Sarah,Dave` is not equal to either `Sarah` or `Steve`. The database doesn't look at the commas and say "oh, that's a list" - it's just a single string of characters that happens to have a comma character every now and then

There are nasty quick hacks to so-so achieve what you want, using LIKE and string concat but they aren't worthy of an answer, to be honest

You need to change your database structure to include a new table that tracks the task id and the employee(s) id it is/was assigned to. After doing that, you'll be able to use IN on the employee id column as you're expecting to with this query